# Holding a spear in two hands

Tags: bones

How can I make this skeleton hold this spear?

Here's what I tried:
[image]

Obviously this doesn't work and I'm all out of ideas.

There's no IK on the skeleton and I don't want it, it's an existing animation from Mixamo that I'm using just temporarily. If it can't be done without IK then I'll just animate it keyframe by keyframe and be done with it.

Comment: Is the existing animation supposed to be holding a spear?

Comment: it seems difficut without IK, what you could do if you end up giving it IK, is make the 2 IK targets (left and right hand controllers) stick to the spear with a Child Of constraint

Comment: Just a quick idea - the first problem is, are the hands always in the exact same distance? Maybe not, and since a spear cannot be stretched and squashed, you first have to decide which hand is the hand holding fast to the spear and not move around. Then I would parent the spear to that hand. The spear could then get a _Track To_ constraint with the other hand as target (or an empty parented somewhere near the hand) so that the spear points at the right location. So the first hand moves the spear which is rotated towards the second, but might be sliding a bit by the distance between hands.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann that worked. It doesn't have to look perfect, just a placeholder for a prerendered top-down animation until an actual 3D artist can do it. Pls make an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: @TimSim I edited my answer a little bit to make it more pictorial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an easy temporarily solution or placeholder this should work: the first problem is, are the hands always in the exact same distance? Maybe not, and since a spear cannot be stretched and squashed, you first have to decide which hand is the hand holding fast to the spear and not move around.

Then I would parent the spear to that hand. The spear could then get a Track To constraint with the other hand as target (or an empty parented somewhere near the hand) so that the spear points at the right location. So the first hand moves the spear which is rotated towards the second, but might be sliding a bit by the distance between hands.

1. Place the spear in one hand and parent it to that bone. The origin of the spear should be at the hand's location, because the origin will be the pivot point for the spear's movement.

[image: parent spear]

2. Now give it a *Track To* constraint and use the other hand as a target. Figure out which track axis works so that the spear is pointing in the right direction. If this is too rough, maybe parent an empty at a better location close to the other hand and track the spear to this empty.

[image: tracking]

3. Now the spear should be animated with the character.

[image: animation]